# Avoiding one broad column in PivotChart in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

When I have a PivotChart in Excel that only has one column, that column gets unnecessarily big and broad. How do I retain that size somewhat, even though its only one column?

[image: example]

Comment: Your whole chart is also unnecessarily wide, column isn't too wide compared to it. I don't think you can control it easily. Maybe with some macro, changing column width depending on number of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't perfect, but you could try setting the series gap width to 500% (the maximum). Right-click your column, select `Format Data Series`, then in Series Options slide `Gap Width` to the highest setting it will go.

With one column it looks like this:

[image]

With multiple columns it looks like this:

[image]

Not ideal, but better than what you have already :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two pivot charts with different measures embedded in a worksheet and it looks like you are using filters to drill down into certain aspects, which will reduce the top chart to just one column.

If the filter settings result in the top chart having only one column, you could try another approach:

(1) don't use a chart. If it is just one number, use a pivot table and show just the number

(2) use a horizontal bar chart instead of a column chart. It will look better since it will be oriented horizontally. In that case, the height of the chart may be too big for one bar. If so, refer to (1).